# Implementation of the d-dimensional torus

Tags: python, flat, data-representation

I need to create a topological object known as a d-dimensional torus, d >= 2. As an example, a square, whose opposite sides are equivalent, is a 2-dimensional torus. For dimension 3, both the opposite corners and the opposite faces of the cube are equivalent. I ask for help to be able to represent the d-dimensional torus in order to calculate the homology using the GUDHI package. Thanks!

Comment: gudhi.PeriodicCubicalComplex ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution taken from [this tutorial](https://dioscuri-tda.org/Paris_TDA_Tutorial_2021.html) in section 'exercises in Persistent homology':

```py
import gudhi as gd
#Here is our triangulation:
#   0-----3-----4-----0
#   | \   | \   | \   | \   |
#   |   \ |   \ |    \|   \ | 
#   1-----8-----7-----1
#   | \   | \   | \   | \   |
#   |   \ |   \ |   \ |   \ |
#   2-----5-----6-----2
#   | \   | \   | \   | \   |
#   |   \ |   \ |   \ |   \ |
#   0-----3-----4-----0
st = gd.SimplexTree()
st.insert([0,1,8])
st.insert([0,3,8])
st.insert([3,7,8])
st.insert([3,4,7])
st.insert([1,4,7])
st.insert([0,1,4])
st.insert([1,2,5])
st.insert([1,5,8])
st.insert([5,6,8])
st.insert([6,7,8])
st.insert([2,6,7])
st.insert([1,2,7])
st.insert([0,2,3])
st.insert([2,3,5])
st.insert([3,4,5])
st.insert([4,5,6])
st.insert([0,4,6])
st.insert([0,2,6])
# Compute persistence, then Betti numbers
st.persistence(persistence_dim_max=True)
st.betti_numbers()
# Returns [1, 2, 1]
```